# Cannot generate HTML coverage report using Reportgenerator

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, nunit, code-coverage, xunit

I have a .net core project with some Unit Test. I wanted to get a coverage report of it. So, I was following the steps from the following official [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-code-coverage?tabs=linux#system-under-test)

Everything was going fine until the last step where I need to run the following code to generate the HTML report:

```
reportgenerator
-reports:"Path\To\TestProject\TestResults\{guid}\coverage.cobertura.xml"
-targetdir:"coveragereport"
-reporttypes:Html
```

The error I am getting is:
[image]

And the following is the output when generation the xml:

[image]

So, I am kind of lost on how o generate the final HTML report. Could someone assist on this?

By the way, I you might see I am trying it from a Mac using zsh. So, not sure if that could affect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error in console, it looks like the file path that you've specified might be incorrect. I believe when using coverlet, the files are generated under random GUID folder every time.

In first screenshot the path that is visible looks like: **UnitTests/TestResults/{SomeGuid}/coverage.cobertura.xml**

but in 2nd screesshot, the file path shows .**UnitTest/coverage.cobertura.xm**l while generating report. I believe the path where reports are getting generated should be the input to your reports command

I've integrated report generator in my azure devops pipeline, and since we cannot be certain about the GUID, I used below command to find all matching files in root folder

```
reports: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/**/*cobertura.xml'
targetdir: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/CoverageResults'
```

This way it looks for all file ending with cobertura.xml in my source directory, without worrying about exact path.

Answer (score 0):

After some hours trying to figure out what the issue was, I finally found it. This might looks like a silly solution but gosh I wish the official docs mentioned something related to it.

Solution was to put all code in a single line,

Original code (from official docs):

```
reportgenerator
-reports:"Path\To\TestProject\TestResults\{guid}\coverage.cobertura.xml"
-targetdir:"coveragereport"
-reporttypes:Html
```

Fixed:

```
 reportgenerator -reports:"Path\To\TestProject\TestResults\{guid}\coverage.cobertura.xml" -targetdir:"coveragereport" -reporttypes:Html
```

Not sure if the settings in m y terminal could play a role here but having all code in a single line will work.